# No cubemap ("material.envMap") reflection on polygon faces with orthographic cam

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, orthographic

Why won't a [MeshPhongMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=material#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial)'s `envMap` property work on polygonal faces when viewed through an orthographic camera?

It works on spheres but not an IcosahedronGeometry, for example. If I set the [`detail` parameter](http://IcosahedronGeometry(radius%20:%20Float,%20detail%20:%20Integer)) of the IcosahedronGeometry to 2+ (more faces), the envMap begins to show. But if I switch to perspective cam, the envMap is fully visible even with `detail` of 0.

This is what it looks like with perspective cam, note the cubemap reflection of some clouds:

[image]

This is what it looks like with orthogonal cam and `detail` is 0, note the lack of cubemap reflection (please ignore the warping of the image):

[image]

Orthogonal cam, `detail` is 1; cubemap reflection is back:

[image]

The only difference between these two versions of the script is the camera.

Here's the code I'm using to create this object:

```
import uvGridImg from './img/grid.png';
import nxImg from './img/nx_50.png';
import pxImg from './img/px_50.png';
import nyImg from './img/ny_50.png';
import pyImg from './img/py_50.png';
import nzImg from './img/nz_50.png';
import pzImg from './img/pz_50.png';

const envTexture = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load([
    pxImg, //right
    nxImg, //left
    pyImg, //top
    nyImg, //bottom
    pzImg, //back
    nzImg, //front
])
envTexture.mapping = THREE.CubeReflectionMapping
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(uvGridImg)
const icosahedronGeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 0)
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()
material.map = texture;
material.envMap = envTexture;

///An attempt to explicitly set every potentially relevant property...

material.envMapIntensity = 0.0;
material.transparent = false;
material.opacity = 1.0;
material.depthTest = true;
material.depthWrite = true;
material.alphaTest = 0.0;
material.visible = true;
material.side = THREE.FrontSide;
material.flatShading=true;
material.roughness = 0.0;
material.color.setHex(0xffffff);
material.emissive.setHex(0x0);
material.specular.setHex(0xffffff);
material.shininess = 30.0;
material.wireframe = false;
material.flatShading = false;
material.combine = THREE.MultiplyOperation;
material.reflectivity = 1.0;
material.refractionRatio = 1.0;
const icosahedron = new THREE.Mesh(icosahedronGeometry, material)
icosahedron.position.x = 0
scene.add(icosahedron);
```

For an MVCE, please [see the example from this tutorial](https://sbcode.net/threejs/meshphongmaterial/) (you will have to add your own orthographic cam to compare with the given perspective cam). Here are [image files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg6FD.jpg) for the textures.

**UPDATE** It seems like all non-spherical geometries cannot render a cubemap reflection correctly thru an orthographic cam. The plane, cylinder, box geometries all fail to render a environment map reflection beyond painting the entire face one uniform reflective color. The sphere, lathe, *hedron geometries (at high levels of detail) will render cubemap reflections.

Is there any way around this? This seems like a huge limitation while working with orthographic cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

- With perspective cameras, the reflective "rays" separate as they get further away from the camera, reflecting a wider angle of the envMap.
- With an ortho camera these reflective "rays" do not separate because they're parallel. So the reflection on a flat face is a very narrow angle of the envMap.

See this demo I quickly put together to demonstrate what you're seeing:
[image]

- It seems to work on spheres because when the parallel orthographic "rays" bounce off a rounded surface, these rays grow wider apart. They are no longer parallel (as is the case with a Perspective camera).

You can see the reflections still work on your demo because the faces alternate between light and dark as you rotate them. You're just looking at a much narrower segment of the envMap:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, makes total sense.